# Matching variables with Subscripts yielding True and False

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I am trying match variables with subscripts just returning true or false depending if pattern is matched. My try is to use `Cases`. However the following does not return a match

```
Cases[Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, l_] /; l > 1]
```

Moreover, if this would work there must something nicer than

```
Length[    Cases[Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, l_] /; l > 1]]>=1
```

Comment: `Cases[{Subscript[x, 2]}, Subscript[x, l_] /; l > 1]` , `MatchQ[Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, l_] /; l > 1]`for just single test.

Comment: MatchQ[( Subscript[x, 2])^2, _ Subscript[x, l_] _ /; l > 1] does not work, I want to check if it occurs anywhere in the term i.e. would the rule  Subscript[x, l_] _ /; l > 1:> 5   change something

Comment: That's because your use of `MatchQ` there is a bit wacky. Perhaps clarify more precisely what you want in the OP? It seems perhaps `Cases[Level[expression, Infinity], Subscript[x, l_] /; l > 1]` might be what you're after.

Comment: `Not@FreeQ[(Subscript[x, 2])^2, Subscript[x, l_] /; l > 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use either `MatchQ`:

```
MatchQ[Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, _?(# > 1 &)]]
```

or `FreeQ` with `Not`:

```
!FreeQ[Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, _?(# > 1 &)]]
```